# Django page not reloading

Tags: django

This problem only affects my production server, annoyingly - I can't replicate it on a development copy (Postgres and Apache, like production) or on my desktop. It doesn't seem to be affected by Django cache settings either. The workflow is:

1. /edit/$id make some edits, redirects to
2. /done is rendered, with link back to /view/$id
3. /view/$id page doesn't reload.

At step 3 a stale version is shown. I put this as the first line of the view:

```
print "RELOADING PAGE: " + unicode(now)
```

...and it is only triggered when I refresh the page; clicking on the link in (2) doesn't show it.

The cache settings I've tried are:

```
CACHES ={
    'default': {
        #'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        #'LOCATION':'127.0.0.1:11211',
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'myapp-cache',
    }
}
```

...plus commenting out the entire CACHES block.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a long expiry date in the headers from a setting in an apache vhosts file. No idea why it only affected some pages on the Django application, but removing it has fixed things.